# how to add custom elements in forward tag in struts-config

Tags: java, struts-1

I am new to struts 1.x i have used struts forward tag in my application like this

```
<struts-config>

<action-mappings>

    <action
        path="/Welcome"
        type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction"
        parameter="/pages/Welcome.jsp"/>

</action-mappings>
```

but in an application i am watching this approach

```
<action path="/getUserGrp" type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction"
        className="com.mj.metal.mapping.AutoActionMapping" parameter="/getUserGrp.screen">
        <set-property property="requireSignIn" value="true" />
        <forward name="requireSignIn" path="/getSignIn.do" />
        <forward name="failure" path="/errorHome.screen" />
        <forward name="invalidAccess" path="/underPrivileged.screen" />
    </action>
```

why className is used with forward action? and parameter is generally a method name like mapping dispatch. Can anyone explain the meaning of this tag?

Answer (score 1):

The `clasName` attribute is optional and is used if you've created your own custom ActionMapping class.

The `set-property` element is used to initialize the properties in your custom ActionMapping class.

Read [this](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23734&seqNum=5) for more info

Comment: thanks this article is pretty helpful,but can you show me a working example of this action>>